# Output from GitHub action is empty

Tags: shell, github, github-actions, building-github-actions

I'm creating my first GitHub action and I can't figure out why the output is empty.

**action.yml**

```yaml
name: "Run Endtest functional tests"
description: "Register a deployment event with Endtest and run the functional tests"
branding:
  icon: play-circle
  color: white
inputs:
  app_id:
    description: 'The Endtest App ID for your account. You can get it from the https://endtest.io/settings page.'
    required: true
  app_code:
    description: 'The Endtest App Code for your account. You can get it from the https://endtest.io/settings page.'
    required: true
  api_request:
    description: 'The Endtest API request for starting the test execution.'
    required: true
  number_of_loops:
    description: 'The number of times the API request for fetching the results will be sent once every 30 seconds.'
    required: true

outputs:
  test_suite_name:
    description: "The name of the test suite"
  configuration:
    description: "The configuration of the machine or mobile device on which the test was executed"
  test_cases:
    description: "The number of test cases"
  passed:
    description: "The number of assertions that have passed"
  failed:
    description: "The number of assertions that have failed"
  errors:
    description: "The number of errors that have been encountered"
  start_time:
    description: "The timestamp for the start of the test execution."
  end_time:
    description: "The timestamp for the end of the test execution."
  #detailed_logs:
    #description: "The detailed logs for the test execution"
  #screenshots_and_video:
    #description: "The URLs for the screenshts and video recordings of the test execution"

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - run: sudo apt-get install jq
      shell: bash 
    - run: sudo chmod +x ${{ github.action_path }}/test.sh
      shell: bash 
    - run: echo "${{ inputs.api_request }}"
      shell: bash 
    - run: ${{ github.action_path }}/test.sh ${{ inputs.app_id }} ${{ inputs.app_code }} "${{ inputs.api_request }}" ${{ inputs.number_of_loops }} 
      shell: bash
```

**test.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
hash=$(curl -X GET --header "Accept: */*" "${3}")
for run in {1.."${4}"}
do
  sleep 30
  result=$(curl -X GET --header "Accept: */*" "https://endtest.io/api.php?action=getResults&appId=${1}&appCode=${2}&hash=${hash}&format=json")
  if [ "$result" == "Test is still running." ]
  then
    status=$result
    # Don't print anything
  elif [ "$result" == "Processing video recording." ]
  then
    status=$result
    # Don't print anything
  elif [ "$result" == "Stopping." ]
  then
    status=$result
  elif [ "$result" == "Erred." ]
  then
    status=$result
    echo $status
  elif [ "$result" == "" ]
  then
    status=$result
    # Don't print anything
  else
     testsuitename=$( echo "$result" | jq '.test_suite_name' )
     configuration=$( echo "$result" | jq '.configuration' )
     testcases=$( echo "$result" | jq '.test_cases' )
     passed=$( echo "$result" | jq '.passed' )
     failed=$( echo "$result" | jq '.failed' )
     errors=$( echo "$result" | jq '.errors' )
     #detailedlogs=$( echo "$result" | jq '.detailed_logs' )
     #screenshotsandvideo=$( echo "$result" | jq '.screenshots_and_video' )
     starttime=$( echo "$result" | jq '.start_time' )
     endtime=$( echo "$result" | jq '.end_time' )   
     
     echo $testsuitename
     echo $configuration
     echo $testcases
     echo $passed
     echo $failed
     echo $errors
     echo $starttime
     echo $endtime
     
     echo "::set-output name=test_suite_name::$testsuitename"
     echo "::set-output name=configuration::$configuration"
     echo "::set-output name=test_cases::$testcases"
     echo "::set-output name=passed::$passed"
     echo "::set-output name=failed::$failed"
     echo "::set-output name=errors::$errors"
     echo "::set-output name=start_time::$starttime"
     echo "::set-output name=end_time::$endtime"
     #echo "::set-output name=detailed_logs::$detailedlogs"
     #echo "::set-output name=screenshots_and_video::$screenshotsandvideo"
     exit 0
  fi
done
exit
```

I've published that action on the GitHub Marketplace and I'm trying to use it / test it from another repository like this:

**main.yml**

```yaml
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: echo Hello, world!
        
      - name: Run Endtest functional tests
        id: endtest_functional_tests
        uses: endtest-technologies/github-run-tests-action@v1.3.0.0.3
        with:
          app_id: "85205402"
          app_code: "79973826"
          api_request: "https://endtest.io/api.php?action=runTestSuite&appId=85205402&appCode=79973826&testSuite=106877&selectedPlatform=windows&selectedOs=a&selectedBrowser=chrome&selectedResolution=d&selectedLocation=sanfrancisco&selectedCases=491130&writtenAdditionalNotes="
          number_of_loops: 6
          
      - name: Get the test suite name output
        run: echo "${{ steps.endtest_functional_tests.outputs.test_suite_name }}"
        
      - name: Get the configuration output
        run: echo "${{ steps.endtest_functional_tests.outputs.configuration }}"

      
      - name: Get multiple outputs
        run: |
          echo "${{ steps.endtest_functional_tests.outputs.test_suite_name }}"
          echo "${{ steps.endtest_functional_tests.outputs.configuration }}"
```

Looking at the logs from the build. I can see that my action is successfully called, the API request starts, I can see the output which is printed out until the part with `::set-output`.

And the outputs generated by my GitHub action are empty.

[image: build output]

I would really appreciate some help on this one, since I've been trying to make it work for the last 2 days.

From what I read, it should be possible to use the `::set-output` from a .sh file, like this person did in this [article](https://www.philschmid.de/create-custom-github-action-in-4-steps).

Comment: That huge `if ... elif ... else` wants to be a `case` statement when it grows up. Repeatedly calling `jq` on small strings also looks like it should be refactored but I can't quickly say exactly how.

Comment: @tripleee Fair point. That code must go through a refactoring. Any ideas on why the ::set-ouput doesn't seem to work in my case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're just setting the outputs of the last step of your action but not the action's outputs.

You have to set the `value` of your action's outputs using the output of the step (as per https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#outputs-for-composite-actions).

```
name: "Run Endtest functional tests"
description: "Register a deployment event with Endtest and run the functional tests"
branding:
  icon: play-circle
  color: white
inputs:
  [...]
outputs:
  test_suite_name:
    description: "The name of the test suite"
    value: ${{ steps.run-script.outputs.test_suite_name }}
  [...]

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - run: sudo apt-get install jq
      shell: bash 
    - run: sudo chmod +x ${{ github.action_path }}/test.sh
      shell: bash 
    - run: echo "${{ inputs.api_request }}"
      shell: bash 
    - run: ${{ github.action_path }}/test.sh ${{ inputs.app_id }} ${{ inputs.app_code }} "${{ inputs.api_request }}" ${{ inputs.number_of_loops }} 
      shell: bash
      id: run-script
```